# gpgv: keyblock resource `/root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/libguestfs.keyring': No such file or directory

Tags: rpmbuild

ERROR:

```
[root@localhost SPECS]# rpmbuild -ba libguestfs.spec
Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.xxzZTr
+ umask 022
+ cd /root/rpmbuild/BUILD
++ mktemp -d
+ tmphome=/tmp/tmp.BAJzdrk0ne
+ gpgv2 --homedir /tmp/tmp.BAJzdrk0ne --keyring 
/root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/libguestfs.keyring /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/libguestfs-
1.36.3.tar.gz.sig /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/libguestfs-1.36.3.tar.gz

gpgv: keyblock resource `/root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/libguestfs.keyring': No such 
file or directory
gpgv: Signature made Fri Mar 24 16:46:40 2017 EDT using RSA key ID E1B768A0
gpgv: Can't check signature: No public key
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.xxzZTr (%prep)
```

I do not have `/root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/**libguestfs.keyring**` file
and I want to know how it came?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to build the RHEL 7.4 libguestfs package?  The keyring file should be included in the source RPM.  If you deleted it somehow then you can get it from the Fedora package here: https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/libguestfs/tree/master

You can also try the RHEL 7.5 preview packages (which include source) here: https://www.redhat.com/archives/libguestfs/2017-November/msg00006.html

Comment: I want to directly modify the Windows VM disk files, but this feature is disabled in the official package.I follow the centos7 source code to compile the official website, but found errors when using supermin5, and later found that you can use the patch to solve.

Comment: I follow this tutorial
https://www.redhat.com/archives/libguestfs/2017-November/msg00006.html
But still can not directly modify ntfs disk